# Kworker process going crazy! CPU at 100%

Tags: cpu-load

I've looked around everywhere and can't find the answer to this problem. Forgive me but i'm pretty noob with linux and ubuntu in general.. But none of the posted questions (and i've looked through dozens) are helping me at all... help?

[kworker going crazy top image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdzN7.png)

Comment: Definitely not a duplicate.. those answers do not help as said in my original message. come on now man :(

Comment: I'd rather not do this.. It was working fine before I have no idea what went wrong and I don't want to throttle my CPU for nothing.

Comment: It's common for your Plex media server to run at high CPU%: https://forums.plex.tv/discussions/tagged/high-cpu-load

Comment: I'm talking about kworker, not plex. Plex is not the problem.

Comment: Please don't change the title to say "FIXED". The proper way of noting that is to accept an answer below by clicking the checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 0):

Fix: unplugged monitor from system. Perhaps a video driver going crazy?

Comment: No, it's not. Plex was using your CPU, and probably doing a lot of IO, leading to high load on kworker.